# Distribution of sum of independent Poisson variables?

Tags: probability

The number of text messages sent by Mario in an hour and the one sent by Ted are two independent Poisson random variables with mean 3. Let N be the total number of texts sent by the two guys between 10 and 11.
I want to calculate $$ \mathbb{P}(N \leq 1)$$

This is my reasoning: 
I can formulate the request like this: 
$$\mathbb{P}[\text{Ted sends a message, Mario doesn't send a message}] + $$
$$\mathbb{P}[\text{Ted doesn't send a message, Mario sends a message}] + $$
$$\mathbb{P}[\text{no messagges sent by both}] + $$
The first and the second are the same, so I calculate just one:
Using poisson: 
$\mathbb{P}[\text{Ted sends a message, Mario doesn't send a message}] = (e^{-3} \cdot \frac{3^1}{1!})(e^{-3} \cdot \frac{3^0}{0!})$
Then I calculate the probability that no one sends a message:
$(e^{-3} \cdot \frac{3^0}{0!})(e^{-3} \cdot \frac{3^0}{0!})$

But the result should be $7e^{-6}$, while mine is $13e^{-6}$. Can someone give me some pointers?

Comment: If $X_i\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda_i)$ are independent for $i=1,2$, then $X_1+X_2\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$. Does this help?

Comment: Your reasoning is fine but $\frac{3^0}{0!}\frac{3^0}{0!}+\frac{3^1}{1!}\frac{3^0}{0!}+\frac{3^0}{0!}\frac{3^1}{1!}=1+3+3=7$

Comment: How did you get $13$ ?  If it is $1+2\cdot 3+2\cdot 3$ then you seem to have multipled by 2 where you should not have.

Comment: My corrected version of your method: $e^{-3}(e^{-3})+2e^{-3}(3e^{-3}).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X_1 \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_1 = 3)$ and, independently, 
$X_2 \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_2 = 3),$ Then
$$Y = X_1+X_2 \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 6).$$
Then $P(Y \le 1) = P(Y = 0)+P(Y=1) = e^{-6}(1+6) = 0.0174.$ which can be evaluated using
the PDF (or PMF) of $\mathsf{Pois}(6).$

```
ppois(1, 6)
## 0.01735127
```

Comment: +1 for the neatness and clearness